# Multithreading with XDocument.Load

Tags: xml, vb.net, multithreading, linq-to-xml

I am trying to make my code work in a separate thread but can't make it work.
I have tried following several different multi-threading examples from the internet using delegates, but nothing fixed my problem.

I need to load data from an XML file via a URL and then show some data from the XML in labels.  Loading the XML sometimes takes a long time and my application is not responding while the loading is in process.  I don't know what else I should try.

Here's an example that works to load the XML without multi-threading (makes the UI non-responsive):

```vb
Dim xmlRoot1 As XElement = XDocument.Load("http://example.com/api/books.xml").Root
Label1.Text = xmlRoot1.<bookstore>.<book>(0).<title>.Value
Label2.Text = xmlRoot1.<bookstore>.<book>(1).<title>.Value
' ...
```

And here is an example of the XML that I am loading:

```xml
<xml>
<bookstore>
    <book>
        <title>Everyday Italian</title>
        <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
        <year>2005</year>
        <price>30.00</price>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>Harry Potter</title>
        <author>J K. Rowling</author>
        <year>2005</year>
        <price>29.99</price>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>XQuery Kick Start</title>
        <author>James McGovern</author>
        <year>2003</year>
        <price>49.99</price>
    </book>
    <book>
        <title>Learning XML</title>
        <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
        <year>2003</year>
        <price>39.95</price>
    </book>
    </bookstore>
</xml>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio 2012 and the 4.5 framework, or higher, you have access to the `Async` and `Await` keywords which make things like this much easier.  However, you can only use the `Await` keyword on a `Task` object.  Since `XDocument` regrettably does not provide a convenient `LoadAsync` method that returns a `Task` object, it's more difficult to use it with the *Task-Based Asynchronous Pattern* (TAP).  The simplest way is to create a method like this:

```vb
Public Async Function LoadXDocumentAsync(uri As String) As Task(Of XDocument)
    Dim t As New Task(Of XDocument)(Function() XDocument.Load(uri))
    t.Start()
    Return Await t
End Function
```

Then you can call it like this:

```vb
Dim doc As XDocument = Await LoadXDocumentAsync("http://example.com/api/books.xml")
Label1.Text = doc.Root.<bookstore>.<book>(0).<title>.Value
Label2.Text = doc.Root.<bookstore>.<book>(1).<title>.Value
```

However, by calling the `Start` method on the `Task` object, like that, it likely starts a new thread to accomplish the work.  If you are worried that it will take a long time to parse the XML, that's the best thing to do anyway, but if you are only concerned about the download-time, it's technically inefficient to start a separate thread just to have it sit there idle while the XML is downloaded from the URI.  So, while it's a little bit more complicated, if you are only concerned about the download being performed asynchronously, it's technically more efficient to do something like this:

```vb
Public Async Function LoadXDocumentAsync(uri As String) As Task(Of XDocument)
    Dim client As New WebClient()
    Return XDocument.Parse(Await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync(uri))
End Function
```

You can then call it in the same way as the first example.  This second example takes advantage of the fact that the `WebClient` class does provide a task-based `Async` method that we can use.  Therefore, even though `XDocument` doesn't provide a task-based `Async` method, we can still at least download the XML using the task-based `WebClient` method and then, once we get it, just parse the XML string with the `XDocument` object back on the calling thread.

Presumably, Microsoft will be adding a `LoadAsync` method to the `XDocument` class in some future version of the framework, but until then you have to make the `Async` function yourself, like I did in the above examples.

If you are not able to utilize TAP, I would suggest using the `BackgroundWorker` component.  For instance:

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Private _doc As XDocument

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
        _doc = XDocument.Load("http://example.com/api/books.xml")
    End Sub

    Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
        Label1.Text = _doc.Root.<bookstore>.<book>(0).<title>.Value
        Label2.Text = _doc.Root.<bookstore>.<book>(1).<title>.Value
    End Sub
End Class
```